# Who will calculate new Date() in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to add a creation date into my document.

```
db.collection.insert({'createdAt': new Date()})
```

The Question is who will evaluate the new date? Will it be on client side or on server side? We want to make sure, that all dates have the same base -> the time of the server.

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing a Javascript object here (the document to insert) on the client. As part of that you call an expression `new Date()`, the *result of which* will become part of that object. Just like if you did `{a : 1 + 2 + myFunction(3) }`. All these expressions are evaluated in the client application.

If you want a server-side timestamp, you can use the [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) atomic update operator.